# Using class and ngClass together

Tags: angular

Below is my code

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="orderTbl" [ngClass]="{'maxZeroHeight':maxZeroHeight}>
```

Is it possible to use like above or is there a different way

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: yes , you can do it.

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: You can use both class and ngClass as the first one gives you the opportunity to apply a class that you want to implement in all cases under any circumstances and the later to apply classes conditionally.

Comment: Thanks it worked

Comment: This is a beginner question with no reference/guidance to this being a duplicate. Why is this down-voted?

Comment: <hr class="d-sm-block" [ngClass]="{
          'd-none': true
        }" /> This code is supposed to hide the line but irrespective of the output of the boolean expression, I am still seeing the line. what is the issue?

Answer (score 4):

`[ngClass]` you should use when there are multiple classes to be applied based on the expression. You should use `[class.classname]="expression"` for single expression and single class to be applied.

Otherwise there is no issue, whatever you have mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

There is **No issue** with using ***both*** `class` and `[ngClass]` together in Angular.

> - `class` still applies all class styles respectively.
> - `[ngClass]`applies conditional classes.

They work together.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it worked having both class and ngclass together, also there is another way